# Django unexpected keyword argument 'id'

Tags: python, django

i'm trying to use arguments on django but when middleware is working on the views.py function, it returns me this error: ***call**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'id'*.

views.py function

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .middleware import SampleMiddleware

@SampleMiddleware
def myfunc(request, id):
    return HttpResponse(id)
```

This is my middleware

```
class SampleMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response
```

This is the URL

```
path('myfunc/<id>', views.myfunc, name='myfunc'),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A middleware class isn't a decorator. In order to use it as one you'd have to wrap it with the [`decorator_from_middleware`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/utils/#django.utils.decorators.decorator_from_middleware) utility.